# android opengl es 1.1 - drawing glitch on certain devices - screenshots inside

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

The top image is the undesired result (it also seems to flicker).
The bottom image is what I would like the render to look like on ALL devices.

[image: Glitchy render]

[image: Good render]

Hello, I seem to be having problems with rendering a textured square to my galaxy s4, but not on my my gt p3113 tablet...

Here is the code from my GLRenderer:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    manObjects.draw(gl, 0, 0);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
{
    if (height == 0)
    { // Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1; // Making Height Equal One
    }

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); // Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Projection Matrix

    // respect the height:width ratio of the window.
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, -1f, 1f, 1.6f, -1.6f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Modelview Matrix
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
{
    // Settings
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Enable Texture Mapping
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH); // Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f); // Black Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f); // Depth Buffer Setup

    // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND); // Enable blending
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Disable depth test
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Load textures
    manObjects.load(gl, mContext);
}
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? And more specifically why it works on one device and not on the other?

Draw code:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl, float x, float y)
{
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texPointers[0]);
    tSquare[0].draw(gl);
}

public void drawBLACK(GL10 gl)
{
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    gl.glScalef(1f, 1.6f, 1);
    gl.glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1);
    tSquare[0].draw(gl);
    gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

tSquare[0].draw(gl):

```
public void draw(GL10 gl)
{
    //Enable the vertex, texture and normal state
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    //Point to our buffers
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    //Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Comment: instead of GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, -1f, 1f, 1.6f, -1.6f); try using gl.glOrthof(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, -1.0f, 1.0f);

Comment: also can you put up your draw() code?

Comment: try commenting out gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f); and gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST); too because you are using orthographic projection thats bound to cause problems

Comment: Added to original post (both the draw black rectangle, and the original draw star code)

Comment: also: tried the gl.glOrthof(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, -1.0f, 1.0f); suggestion, and the "try commenting out gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f); and gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);" one... problem remained unchanged. (tested it without the rectangle cover)

Comment: The strange thing is that it works fine (without the cover) on that gt p3113 tablet, just not on the GS4...

Comment: can you put up draw() for tSquare[0].draw(gl);

Comment: instead of using onSurfaceChanged() and onSurfaceCreated() for arranging your gl calls, make them in order in your onDrawFrame() method, its definetly the order in which your gl calls are being made

Comment: just make variable width and height from onSurfaceChanged() and make all the calls in order in your onDrawFrame()

Comment: So i should move every gl.xxxxx line from onSurfaceChanged() and onSurfaceCreated() to onDrawFrame()? I will try that. By the way, thanks a lot for all your help JRowan! So I tried adding all the calls from both methods to onDrawFrame(), in the same order, and the result was the same... I tried with the onSurfaceCreated calls first, then the onSurfaceChanged, and also the inverse; still same result.

Comment: i posted an answer, just play around with it, im pretty sure between onSurfaceChanged and onSurfaceCreated the calls are getting mixed up between devices, i think i had the same problem before, you can use clearcolor instead of clear or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of my onDrawFrame, try making your gl calls in onDrawFrame instead

first make

```
public int width, height;
```

then

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) { 
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
```

then onDrawFrame something like this

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        manObjects.draw(gl, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Works almost perfectly, orthof wasn't displaying anything, I had to use ortho2D, which works perfect! Thanks a million

Comment: NOTE: I actually reverted back to the original code I posted, but added the "gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);" line at the top of onDrawFrame(), and it also seems to work. That seems like the "lightest" solution...?

Comment: there you have it my friend

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

I have added another draw before the call that draws the star. This added draw call draws a giant black rectangle that covers the entire screen...

I feel like I'm only masking the problem and not really fixing it...
Thoughts?